# Blender imported svg (path numbering, polylines)

Tags: scripting, import, svg

I'm working with a developer friend in order to create a script to make my repetitive work easier. To sum it up: I have dozens of SVGs, all of them with layers in the same order and same names. I want to import each one sequentially into Blender, do some operations, render, and go to the next one etc. For SVG work I use inkscape.

The problem I've encountered is that there are times that blender imports some layers as polylines (from what I can see, randomly) and some times it doesn't keep the order the layers have on the original file.

As blender renames the layers to path+number I can't find a way to correlate them to the original file. Is there a way of taking into account the original names when importing?

Thank you

Comment: After some basic tests I assume Blender parses the SVG file as an XML and iterates over graphical elements in the same order they appear in the original SVG file. You can use XML or SVG parsers to follow the same logic and rename and reorganize the objects in your scene. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857818/python-svg-parser
And: https://github.com/meerk40t/svgelements